# Por que colocar JavaScript, CSS e imagens em outro servidor?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Na maioria dos sites percebi que eles usam outro servidor para carregar scripts, CSS e imagens. Porque eles utilizam?

Comment: Respostas que dizem que isso é a mesma coisa CDN estão recebendo meu -1, pois CDN é só UMA das formas de se fazer isso. Pra quem não sabe, **[CDN (Content delivery network)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)** é uma rede de espelhamento em vários servidores para que o acesso seja feito de maneira mais eficiente, seja por distribuição geográfica ou divisão de banda e recursos. É perfeitamente possível e comum alguém dividir os _assets_ entre servidores extra, para fins de organização e performance SEM USAR CDN, e isso também se aplica ao que foi perguntado.

Comment: PS: Não sou contra se fazer uma resposta falando de CDN. O que não dá é pra aceitar uma afirmação de que CDN é sinônimo do que foi perguntado.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

É uma técnica chamada de [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). Essa técnica consiste em requisitar o arquivo de um servidor muito usado. Você pode importar por exemplo um script do jQuery do servidor da Google.

**Mas por que?**

Bom, se o usuário já tiver entrado em um site que requisitou o jQuery do Google, e entrar no seu site que também está utilizando o mesmo URL para requisitar, ele já vai ter armazenado em cache e por tanto aumenta o desempenho consideravelmente já que não vai precisar usar de novo. Assim como se o seu site for o primeiro, já vai armazenar no cache do navegador o arquivo que você requisitou para que este não precise ser requisitado novamente em outros sites.

A desvantagem é que para funcionar perfeitamente as URLs requisitadas precisam ser iguais (Para que o navegador entenda que o arquivo já está no cache). Além disso se o seu site for o primeiro a requisitar determinada URL, não vai haver cache, e o carregamento vai ficar mais lento pelo menos nesta primeira visita já que a requisição será para um servidor externo.

Outra desvantagem é que se o servidor que hospeda o arquivo estiver offline ou inacessível no momento da requisição, o arquivo deixa de ser requisitado, retornando um erro 404. Porém você pode tratar isso com uma verificação que carregue uma versão local neste caso.

**Veja um exemplo:**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-1.2.1.min.js">\<script>');
</script>
```

Comment: Quanto a solução para caso o servidor CDN esteja inacessível, me corrija se eu estiver errado: Mas acredito que a abertura do site demoraria vários segundos, pois o navegador vai esperar por vários segundos a resposta do servidor CDN, até considerar *timeout*.

Comment: Concordo @Andrey, eu particularmente prefiro usar apenas arquivo do meu servidor mesmo, assim evito essas possibilidades, mas cada caso é um caso ;)

Answer (score 11):

Existem várias formas de se implementar este tipo de solução, a mais comum atualmente (e a qual você provavelmente está se referindo) é chamada de CDN (Content Delivery Network). Apesar de estar sendo amplamente utilizada no meio WEB hoje em dia, esta prática não é só vantagens, e seu uso deve ser pensado levando em consideração o seu projeto e como você pensa em disponibilizar sua aplicação.

#### Casos onde se utilizar:

- Web aplicativos em geral
- Sites em geral
- Blogs em geral

#### Casos onde se não utilizar:

- Sistema intranet, onde o servidor fica dentro da própria empresa. Nestes casos vale mais a pena não utilizar CDNs, já que os arquivos CSS e JavaScript ficariam em um servidor da própria rede e o delay / trafego seria ínfimo. Além do mais, caso a internet caia, um sistema intranet deveria continuar em pleno funcionamento, caso você esteja utilizando CDN, essa garantia já não existiria.
- Projeto que preza por extrema performance, onde você quer reduzir o número de requisições ao máximo, compilando todos os seus arquivos JavaScript e CSS em um só, neste caso como você está gerando um arquivo customizado (com as suas funções e plugins juntos) não seria possível usar um CDN (a não ser que você criasse um, mas ai lá se vai uma das vantagens de se usar CDN, que veremos abaixo).

#### Vantagens do CDN:

- Economia de banda;
- Economia de recursos do servidor;
- Entrega mais rápida de recursos.

**Economia de banda:**
Cada vez que um usuário fizer uma requisição dos arquivos do seu projeto que estão no CDN essa requisição vai para o servidor CDN e não o seu, o que, em larga escala, acaba por te economizar muita transferência de dados.

**Economia de recursos do servidor:**
Embora este problema possa ser resolvido com cache (no lado cliente e/ou servidor), ainda assim em algum caso extremo pode ser que ele te ajude a economizar recursos do servidor, já que ele não vai precisar se preocupar em entregar os arquivos a cada requisição, este trabalho é repassado ao CDN.

**Entrega mais rápida de recursos:**
Os grandes provedores de CDN geralmente possuirem servidores em várias partes do mundo, o que garante um menor tempo de latência das requisições e do envio dos arquivos para o usuário.

#### Desvantagens:

- Queda na segurança do projeto;
- Cai o CDN, seu projeto quebra.

**Queda na segurança do projeto:**
Caso o CDN que você esteja utilizando seja invadido ou não seja de confiança e tenha os arquivos modificados, você vai estar distribuindo arquivos "fraudulentos" e possivelmente perigosos para os seus usuários.

**Cai o CDN, seu projeto quebra:**
Caso o CDN saia do ar por qualquer motivo que seja, o usuário que acessar seu site não vai receber os arquivos, o que provavelmente vai afetar o funcionamento do seu projeto.

Comment: @Bacco, pesquisei melhor e de fato você estava certo, está corrigido.

Comment: Reverti meu voto, e dei +1. Depois deleto este comment aqui. Espero que o outro -1 seja revertido também, caso tenha sido pelo mesmo motivo.

Answer (score 7):

### Imagens e CSS

Os navegadores são recomendados, na especificação HTTP/1.1, a fazerem no máximo 2 downloads paralelos por host. Se você tem 4 imagens hospedadas no mesmo host, elas serão baixadas duas a duas. Se você tem 4 imagens hospedadas em 2 hosts diferentes, elas serão baixadas simultaneamente.

O mesmo vale para CSS.

### Scripts

Scripts nunca são baixados simultaneamente. O principal motivo para usar um servidor externo, neste caso, é para aproveitar o cache do seu navegador.

Comment: Isso tudo e mais a organização e eficiência que você ganha se configurar cada server pra sua especialidade. Por exemplo, fine-tuning pra arquivos de imagem, e estáticos em geral, outra maquina especializada em linguagem server side, etc.

Answer (score 5):

Porque deixa o carregamento do site mais rápido.

Se tiver um tempo faz um teste.

Chama o Jquery do google e o Jquery do seu servidor, no network o Jquery do Google vai

carregar mais rápido do que o Jquery do seu servidor.

Você só deve ficar atento a permissão, se uma pessoa acessar o seu site no Irã, o Jquery do google não vai carregar, caso isso aconteça utilize o código abaixo

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
if (!window.jQuery) {
    document.write('<script src="/path/to/your/jquery"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```