# Usar ou não usar CSS/JS dentro do PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Usar CSS/JS dentro do PHP, existe diferença se usados em um arquivo externo por exemplo? Muitas páginas tem CSS/JS dentro e também externamente, não seria mais fácil colocar todos juntos do que dividir uma parte no código e outra externa no mesmo servidor?

Qual a maneira correta de usá-los? E por quê?

Comment: "dentro do PHP" seria onde exatamente? Colocando todo o código dentro do arquivo `.php` ou usando os arquivos no mesmo servidor?

Comment: Colocando todo o código dentro do php, sem arquivos externos. @Kazzkiq

Comment: @Kazzkiq Sua resposta era boa, se quiser postar com pequenas adaptações na [pergunta que o Sergio indicou](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11753/colocar-arquivos-em-outro-servidor/11755#11755), funcionaria.

Comment: @bfavaretto pois é, eu reli a pergunta aqui e achei que minha resposta ficou meio fora de contexto, por sorte salvei ela num bloco de notas antes de deletar, ela foi usada na [outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/20883/1754).

Comment: Me aventuraria a responder de maneira mais extensa se tivesse um pouco mais de tempo, mas vou ousar adiantar já: Não tem certo nem errado. Todas as situações tem vantagens e desvantagens, o melhor é saber quais são, e ver o que se aplica melhor no caso real. Um exemplo simplificado: CSS externo pode ser útil pra ficar no cache do browser, mas em determinados projetos, a carga dele separada e/ou atrasada em relação ao HTML é inaceitável esteticamente. Em outros casos, um CSS gigante dentro de toda página não é bom em termos de velocidade e banda. Vai do caso concreto, independente do recurso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tudo é questão de **rapidez** e **economia de recursos**.

Colocar todo o código dentro da página é inviável, pois as repetições de scripts e folhas de estilo em todas as páginas geram um fluxo muito grande e desnecessário de dados.

Para dar uma noção, vamos supor que seu CSS/JS tenha no total 100kb. Se você colocar todo o código dentro da página, mil acessos vão gerar um total de **98mb** transferidos, um desperdício de bytes.

Ao colocar o CSS e o JS em arquivos externos, eles são baixados **apenas no primeiro acesso**.

Este foi um dos principais argumentos do movimento tableless, ao advogar que o uso de CSS também traria mais rapidez e economia de recursos além do ganho estético.

Como regra geral, faça seu PHP gerar códigos que forem utilizados apenas naquela página e/ou que dependam das preferências do usuário. Se seu sistema permite ao usuário mudar a cor de um elemento, não tem problema gerar o CSS dentro da página.

De forma oposta, exagerar na dose e espalhar seu código em muitos arquivos de script diferentes vai aumentar o número de requisições GET, o que além de deixar o site mais lento, também sai mais caro (serviços como o Amazon S3 cobram pelo número de GETs).

Então, o ideal é:

- deixar seus scripts e folhas de estilo fora do HTML;
- combinar os arquivos JS e CSS antes de passar do desenvolvimento para a produção.

Comment: É uma questão de rapidez e economia de recursos, mas também uma questão de *legibilidade*. Misturar PHP, CSS, JavaScript tudo num só arquivo pode tornar sua aplicação bem ilegível. Por muito tempo houve muita ênfase em mover CSS e JS para outros arquivos porque frequentemente o código ficava confuso. Se sua aplicação começar a ficar ilegível com muito CSS e JS inline, talvez seja o caso de pensar em pô-los em arquivos separados e juntar os arquivos em um só durante a execução (além de usar um minifier). Agora, se o código inline não prejudica a legibilidade, não há problema algum.

Answer (score 1):

Olá amigo.

Além das questões citadas pelo @Ifarroco, utilizar scripts CSS e JS em arquivos externos, também ajuda a criar um código mais limpo e padronizado.
Digamos que seu CSS será utilizado em várias páginas. Criando o mesmo em um arquivo separado, você poderá utilizá-lo onde precisar, somente inserindo o link do arquivo. O mesmo ocorre com o JS.

Espero ter ajudado.