# Preciso de uma recomendação sobre o modo de uso do bootstrap como formatação de templates em uma app Flask

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask

Olá, esta dúvida parece meio básica mas ainda não achei uma resposta consistente.
Gostaria de saber se, ao utilizar o Bootstrap como formatação de um template no FlaskPy, a melhor opção é via CDN, ou seja, anexando o link no arquivo.html [...]

```html
CSS only

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

JS, Popper.js, and jQuery

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapc
```

[...] ou devo baixar os arquivos e anexar na pasta static do app? Em algum dos casos tenho alguma perda de desempenho em meu app?

**Uma observação:** não desejo fazer alterações CSS na estrutura do Bootstrap, apenas usar as formatações básicas disponível pelo framework.

Desde já agradeço a atenção de vocês!

Comment: Mais uma de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11753/por-que-colocar-js-css-e-imagens-em-outro-servidor e mais outra https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303645/como-devo-trabalhar-em-rela%C3%A7ao-a-links-do-bootstrap-e-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vantagem de utilizar CDN é a velocidade de carregamento, além de um serviço preparado para receber milhares de requisições. A desvantagem é não ter certeza sobre o que está do outro lado e não poder definir a otimização no seu próprio site.
Caso prefira usar arquivo local, pode optar pelo arquivo .min que é mais leve que o arquivo normal. No site do bootstrap existe essa opção de download.

Comment: Entendi. Em vários lugares que pesquisei fala isso mesmo, a vantagem de velocidade no carregamento. Enfim, obrigado. Vou pesquisar mais sobre a dica que você deu em relação ao arquivo .min.